# progeny of Vaishya(father) & Mahisya(mother)? (Yagyavalkya Smriti)

Tags: yajnavalkya

According to Yajñavalkya Smriti, What will be the progeny of Vaishya(father) & Mahisya(mother) will be called?

Comment: What do u mean by "Mahisya"

Comment: @YDS  Kshatriya father with vaishya mother gives the progeny Mahishya (Mahisya)

Comment: Do you want references from Manu Smriti as well? or only from Yajnavalkya? @user21378

Comment: @Rickross No Sir I want only from Yajñavalkya Smriti.

Comment: Okay thanks .. @user21378

Comment: @Rickross Sir I have gone throughly through this website. Haven't found any... If you can give a try, page 183. https://archive.org/details/yajnavalkyasmrit00yj/page/193/mode/1up

Comment: Pls don't call me sir :) I might be younger than you. I already have that book of Yajnavalkya Smriti with Mitaksara commentary. I will check in it. But are you sure that Yajnvalkya have mentioned about the issue? Why are you not looking for answers from other scriptures? @user21378

Comment: @Rickross I am sure that Yajñavalkya has mentioned about the issue.

Comment: @Rickross if it's not mentioned then you can tell me from Manusmriti as well.

Comment: Okay I will answer if I find anything in Yajnvalkya or in Manu. @user21378